# ImportError: No module named simplify

Tags: python, nltk

I am getting the following error when trying to import `simplify_wsj_tag`:

```
 File "parser-test2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from nltk.tag.simplify import simplify_wsj_tag
ImportError: No module named simplify
```

The code is very simple:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag.simplify import simplify_wsj_tag
```

I have `nltk` installed so I'm not sure why this error is coming up.

Comment: Open an interpreter, type `nltk.download()`. When the GUI opens up look for simplify and download it.

Comment: You might want to check the import basics (like including `__init__.py` in your directories) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587457/importerror-no-module-named-python?rq=1

Comment: @Coldspeed I was not able to find Simplify or tag in the NLTK Downloader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It used to be in NLTK 2.0, not in the newer version 3.2.4. See the docs [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html).

Also, look at this as well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26980638/7595755.